# Fallout 4 - The Molecular Level - Change Faction

Tags: fallout-4

So I asked the Railroad first to help me build the relay, thinking I was going to be able to ask for help from all three factions. I would've chosen the Minutemen had I known there was only one faction I could ask for help. My question is this: I haven't gone through the relay yet (in an hours-old save), but have built it with the Railroad's help. Can I reject their assistance and change who I want to help me? The answer is likely, "no," as I've already built the relay, but I'd really prefer the Minutemen over the Railroad as they are the most noble of the factions in my estimation.

Comment: I've gone through the Molecular Level quest, and while I haven't completely beaten the game, I'm fairly certain that who you chose to help build the relay doesn't matter. Without trying to spoil much, you _will_ only use the relay once anyway.. So, while I'm fairly sure it won't matter in the end, I'm not certain enough to post this as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm what Unknown Zombie stated in his comment. It does not matter in terms of who you want to ally with for the end of the game.

I can confirm this because I chose the Brotherhood to assist me, and sided with the Institute to get their ending for my first playthrough. And did the opposite on my second playthrough. Neither side really so much as mentioned the fact that I chose their enemy to assist the relay build. It serves no function after that mission anyway.

Comment: It's an OCD thing. I just want the Minutemen to come out on top, to be the heroes. If I side with the Railroad, as I've already done, then they are the heroes. I suppose it doesn't matter much. I'll just play through, then playthrough again. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Actually you can continue doing quests for the Minutemen and still complete the game with them - they're always available to complete the game with even if you mess up with all of the other factions.